# Understanding OWA logs

Tags: macos, logging, macbook-pro, outlook-web-access

I have a number of logs that I think are OWA logs.  Titles such as microsoft.o365.shellg2.owa.js
microsoft.exchange.clients.owa2.client.calcorestrings.localized.min.js

Can anyone help me try and work out if they contain login details/ip addresses/computer details etc on a macbook

Comment: Those are JavaScript files (js), not logs. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?